# Как правильно сделать рекурсию формулы в C++. Возведение в степень не через pow()

Tags: c++, рекурсия

есть формула, которую надо сделать через рекурсию. Число n заданно в файле под названием input.txt

Формула:
Сумма от i=1 до n = 2i/2^i+1

Моя проблема в том что не могу сделать возведение степень не через pow()

Код программы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
double series(int n)
{
  double sum;
  if (n == 0)
  {return 0;}                             //    2i/1+2^i
  else
  {
      sum = ((double)(2*n) / (double)(2*n + 1)) + series(n - 1);
      return sum;
  }
}
int main()
{
  ifstream fin;
  fin.open("input.txt");
  if (!fin) return 1;
int n;
fin >> n;
double sum = series(n);
cout << sum;
fin.close();
return 0;
}
```

По моим расчетам если n=2 то ответ будет 1.466666 приблизительно

Comment: и что не работает?

Comment: Не получается возвести в степень без pow

Comment: Что значит "не получается"? Выдает неправильный результат или получаете ошибку или программа вываливается? Сложно догадаться, какой ожидаемый результат и что реально получаете.

Comment: Где требуется возводить в степень? Вроде выглядит правильно. А я понял вы не можете `2^i` посчитать? И да приведите пожалуйста пример, то есть результат, который вы получаете и результат который вы ожидали увидеть

Comment: Кажется, понял. Реальный вопрос звучит, похоже, так: `как реализовать 2^i не используя pow`, а код в вопросе имеет очень опосредованное отношение. Вас следует исправить вопрос и включить в него только то, что важно. Дополнительная информация только мешает увидеть суть вопроса.

Comment: Требуется возвести в формуле 2 в степень i, результат в моей написанной программе не может быть правильным так как программа считает вот так 1+2i

Comment: Но надо реализовать через рекурсию

Comment: Что именно реализовать через рекурсию: возведение в степень или вычисление формулы?

Comment: возведение в степень в формуле Сумма от i=1 до n = 2i/2^i+1

Comment: Сумма - обычно записывается "сумма **вид i-го члена** по i от **начальное значение** до **конечное значение**" В вашей записи получается, что суммируем не пойми что в диапазоне от 0 до 2i/2^i+1... Было бы неплохо, если бы вы исправили свой вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот как пример кода:

```
double series_step(int i, int n, int fact)
{
    if (i > n)
        return 0;  
    return ((double)i * 2) / ((double)fact + 1) + series_step(i + 1, n, fact * 2);
}

double series(int n) {
    return series_step(1, n, 2);
}
```

То есть начинаем с `i = 1` и `fact = 2` и каждую итерацию мы увеличиваем `i` на 1, а `fact` умножаем на 2

Результат программы при `n = 2`:

```
1.46667
```

Comment: Формула написанная вами 2*i / (2^i +1)  Она будет верна